# Tomcat 6.0.35 - how to bypass new CSRF protection on the manager application?

Tags: solr, tomcat6, csrf

I have a command line script (actually a git post-checkout hook) that reloads my Solr application by doing a cURL to:

```
http://localhost:8080/manager/html/reload?path=/solr
```

Since I upgraded to Ubuntu 13.04, it now fails, where it used to work before the upgrade.

The cause of the problem is that my newer version of Tomcat (6.0.35), has some new CSRF protection and it now returns `403 Access Denied`.

How can I solve the issue and bypass the CSRF protection?

---

More info:

My `/etc/tomcat6/tomcat-users.xml` file:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
  <role rolename="manager"/>
  <user username="tomcat" password="secret" roles="manager"/>
</tomcat-users>
```

The documentation for [Configuring Manager Application access in tomcat](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/manager-howto.html#Configuring%20Manager%20Application%20Access%20%20Configuring%20Manager%20Application%20access%20in%20tomcat) mentions some new manager roles, however my error specifically mentions that the single "manager" role still exists for the moment (and I tried the other roles anyway without success).

Answer (score 0):

(As I was writing the question, I found the answer.) Instead of cURLing to the *HTML* application, I needed to cURL to the "*plain text* interface".

i.e. instead of

```
http://localhost:8080/manager/html/reload?path=/solr
```

Use:

```
http://localhost:8080/manager/reload?path=/solr
```

It turns out:

> The HTML interface is protected against CSRF but the text and JMX interfaces are not.

This fits with the new role called "manager-script". To ensure my app will work in the future I changed my `/etc/tomcat6/tomcat-users.xml` file:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
  <role rolename="manager-gui"/>
  <role rolename="manager-script"/>
  <user username="tomcat" password="secret" roles="manager-gui,manager-script"/>
</tomcat-users>
```